# WHERE clause on subtraction between two columns MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have the following MySQL query that runs absolutely fine:

```
SELECT a.id, a.event_name, c.name, a.reg_limit-e.places_occupied AS places_available, a.start_date
FROM nbs_events_detail AS a, nbs_events_venue_rel AS b, nbs_events_venue AS c,
(SELECT e.id, COUNT(d.event_id) AS places_occupied FROM nbs_events_detail AS e LEFT JOIN nbs_events_attendee AS d ON e.id=d.event_id GROUP BY e.id) AS e
WHERE a.id=b.event_id AND b.venue_id=c.id AND a.id=e.id AND a.event_status='A' AND a.start_date>=NOW()
ORDER BY a.start_date
```

However, I'm trying to add one more `WHERE` clause, in order to filter the results shown in the column created for the subtraction: `a.reg_limit-e.places_occupied AS places_available`

What I've done so far was adding a `WHERE` clause like the following:
`WHERE places_available>0`

However, if I try to use this instruction, the query will fail and no results will be shown. The error reported is the following: `#1054 - Unknown column 'places_available' in 'where clause'`

In `a.reg_limit` I have numbers, in `e.places_occupied` I have numbers generated by the `COUNT` in the sub-query.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [can not use aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html), defined in query, in `WHERE` clause. In order to make your query works, use condition `a.reg_limit-e.places_occupied>0` in `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE` clause is executed before the `SELECT` statement, so it doesn't know about that new alias `places_available`, [the logical order of operations in Mysql](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-SQL-Query-Order-of-Operations.htm) is like this:

> 1. FROM clause
> 2. WHERE clause
> 3. GROUP BY clause
> 4. HAVING clause
> 5. SELECT clause
> 6. ORDER BY clause

As a workaround for this, you can wrap it in a subquery like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      a.id, 
      a.event_name, 
      c.name, 
      a.reg_limit-e.places_occupied AS places_available,  
      a.start_date
    FROM nbs_events_detail AS a
    INNER JOIN nbs_events_venue_rel AS b ON a.id=b.event_id
    INNER JOIN nbs_events_venue AS c ON b.venue_id=c.id 
    INNER JOIN
    (
       SELECT e.id, 
         COUNT(d.event_id) AS places_occupied 
       FROM nbs_events_detail AS e 
       LEFT JOIN nbs_events_attendee AS d ON e.id=d.event_id    GROUP BY e.id
    ) AS e ON a.id=e.id
    WHERE a.event_status='A' AND a.start_date>=NOW()
) AS t
WHERE places_available>0
ORDER BY a.start_date;
```

Also try to use the ANSI-92 `JOIN` syntax instead of the old syntax, and use the explicit `JOIN` instead of mixing the conditions in the `WHERE` clause like what I did.

Answer (score 0):

first: another clause must be add by boolean logic operators ( `AND` or `OR` ) after the first `WHERE` occurance. 
Meaning something like:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE col1 = value
AND col2 = value
```

second: you placed an alias on your substraction, but that wont work in your WHERE clause the way you intend.
You can either write it like this ( my evil/bad suggestion ):

```
SELECT a.id, a.event_name, c.name, a.reg_limit-e.places_occupied AS places_available, a.start_date
FROM nbs_events_detail AS a, nbs_events_venue_rel AS b, nbs_events_venue AS c,
(SELECT e.id, COUNT(d.event_id) AS places_occupied FROM nbs_events_detail AS e LEFT JOIN nbs_events_attendee AS d ON e.id=d.event_id GROUP BY e.id) AS e
WHERE a.id=b.event_id 
AND b.venue_id=c.id 
AND a.id=e.id 
AND a.event_status='A' 
AND a.start_date>=NOW()
AND a.reg_limit-e.places_occupied > 0
ORDER BY a.start_date
```

or you could use a subquery - which would be better performance speaking... as function equations in WHERE clauses are evil and cost performance. See Mahmoud Gamals answer for that query... dont wanna type it here again and dont wanna steal it ;-)